# Integrate NotifyVisitors Javascript Code OPencart

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add the following javascript code into the footer of Opencart (2.0.3) to integrate notifyvisitors app for my website.

But I don't know how and where to add javascript code to enable notifyvisitors app.

```
<div id='notifyvisitorstag'></div>
<script>    
    var notify_visitors = window.notify_visitors || {}; 
    (function() { 
        notify_visitors.auth = { bid_e : '7E8xxxxxxxxxxxx561', bid : '0000`enter code here`', t : '420'};
        var script = document.createElement('script');script.async = true;
        script.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? "//d2933uxo1uhve4.cloudfront.net" : "//cdn.notifyvisitors.com") + '/js/notify-visitors-1.0.js';
        var entry = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        entry.parentNode.insertBefore(script, entry); 
    })();
</script>
```

Please guide.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Notifyvisitors updated plugin is now available at official opencart extension store.

Comment: Posting answers that only consist of a link is strongly discouraged on Stack Overflow. Either delete this answer and post the link as a comment instead, or edit the answer to summarize the relevant part of the article, so that it stands on its own without the link (you can keep the link in, though). Thank you.